# Font not loading sometime because of CORS

Tags: amazon-s3, http-headers, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I created a custom iconfont (like FontAwesome but with custom SVG - I use [fontcustom](http://fontcustom.com/)). SOMETIME my custom font does not load and I get squares instead of icons. Here is the CORS  what I get on the chrome console:

```
Font from origin 'https://dqggv9zcmarb3.cloudfront.net' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://www.coursavenue.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'https://pro.coursavenue.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This seem to happen when I have no cache and I go from https://www.coursavenue.com/ to https://pro.coursavenue.com/. But again, this happen only SOMETIME and if icon doesn't load and I reload the page, it will work.

I have a Rails app, my assets are stored on a S3 bucket with a cloudfront distribution.

Here are my CORS config on S3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>https://*.coursavenue.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Here is my cloudfront cache behavior settings:
[image: Cloudfront settings]

Any ideas? Does the option `Object Caching: Use Origin Cache Headers` is the problem?

Comment: Are you getting this using different browsers? There are some [historical issues](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=103402) you may want to dig into as well.

Comment: Hum, just chrome actually...

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me. In addition to forwarding the Origin header on cloudfront, I had to add an extra header when uploading the font to S3:

```
s3cmd --add-header="Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you selected HTTP and HTTPS.

[image]